# appium Hybrid App - couldn't able to navigate to WebView

Tags: appium

i am new to Appium, trying with Hybrid app which has been developed using Phonegap.
The problem which i am facing is couldn't able to navigate to WebView. upto FrameLayout i can able to drive but after than i couldn't. please guide me. please find my following code used:- 
Envrionment : 
Appium Version : 1.3.4.1 
Device Used: S5 
Android Version : 4.4.2 
java client : 2.1

```
File appDir = new File("Path");
File app = new File(appDir, ".apk"); 
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","S5");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");
capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
capabilities.setCapability("app-package", "packagename"); 
capabilities.setCapability("app-activity", "activity");  
drivers = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),  capabilities);
Set contextNames = drivers.getContextHandles();
for (String contextName : contextNames) {
System.out.println(contextNames); //from the drivers.getContextHandles i am getting only "NATIVE_APP"
}
drivers.context(contextNames.toArray()[0].toString()); 
               drivers.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.Linear   Layout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout"));
drivers.findElement(By.className("android.webkit.WebView"))

 //From here i couldn't able to navigate
drivers.findElement(By.xpath("//android.view.View[@index='0']"));

i have tried with drivers.switchto.window("NATIVE_APP") but haven't worked. 
please guide me.?
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to inspect properties for elements you can keep the application screen open on device/emulator and open a new chrome browser and type chrome://inspect in URL box.
This should show device attached, webview and an Inspect button, clicking on it will open up a new window with page source for the related screen.

In case you want to work with elements in webview through script, switching to webview context would help.

driver.context("WEBVIEW_webviewname");
WEBVIEW_webviewname - name provided to webview for mobile app

Thanks,
Sujata